# jQuery loses ability to read HTML and CSS tags inside AJAX script after location hash change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm experiencing some issues regarding an AJAX script I'm working on.

The page loads perfectly well, and all needed scripts are loaded the same for basic page functionality inside AJAX script, but after hash change, jQuery behaves awkwardly.

Let's take this example.

> The custom jQuery script writes an inline CSS propriety for a specific DIV at page loading:

[image: inline style added by JS script]

> Now, I load the login page for example:

[image: login page hash change]

> I get back to the main page and inline style disappears as well as the basic loaded functionalities cease to exist after Ajax call:

[image]

> *

Any experience on this? Does anyone have a clue why this happens? Or even near it... Seems the script unloads on page/hash change, which I don't believe. Or enters in double loop, therefore doubling the classes for HTML. I don't get it.

Already searched a lot and went trough the coding and is fine becasue it works fine alongside with basic HTML. Would appreciate some thoughts on this matter.

Thanks!

Comment: Footnote: even a click on an anchor link inside the main page causes the DOM to lose CSS inline styles as stated above. Doesn't really need to change hash for AJAX call

Comment: It's likely some code on the page doing something you didn't expect.  If you share some, we might be able to help you find where. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As @AlexMcMillan says, we need to see the code. My guess is that you are loading a new copy of jquery with your ajax call thus breaking all of your existing jquery objects and connections. This would cause all of the symptoms you relate above.